# A Sacks-like forcing

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Given a tree $T\subseteq \omega^{<\omega}$ we call T *superperfect* if

- For all $t \in T$ there is an $s\supseteq t$ such that $s^\smallfrown n \in T$ for all $n\in\omega$, where $s^\smallfrown n$ is the finite sequence in which we add $n$ at the end of $s$.

Has the forcing notion $(P,\supseteq)$ of superperfect trees (in the above sense) been studied ? Is it known under a different name?

Comment: Miller forcing?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The usual definition of "superperfect" is equivalent to "Miller", but the OP's definition isn't the usual one.

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, I see. Reading more closely, that looks a bit more like a Prikry–Silver real, perhaps? (Or a very close variant...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This forcing is introduced and studied, among other things, in:

*Newelski, L.; Rosłanowski, A.*, [**The ideal determined by the unsymmetric game**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2159150), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 117, No. 3, 823-831 (1993). [ZBL0778.03016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0778.03016).

They denote this forcing by $\mathbb{D}_\omega$. They show (Theorem 2.1) that this forcing adds a Cohen real and that it doesn't add any random or dominating reals.  I don't know if it has been studied further in more recent papers.